# Datatables : disable first next previous last and show / search record when processing

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using Datatables 1.9 version

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {"sSearch": "Search all columns:",
                      "sLengthMenu": "Display <select><option value='100'>100</option><option value='200'>200</option></select> records per page"
                     },
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "iDisplayStart": 0,
        "iDisplayLength": 2000,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollY": "500px",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bSortClasses": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
                aoData.push( { "name": "form_data", "value": data } );
        },
        "sAjaxSource": "search.py",
        "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                $.ajax( {
                                "dataType": 'json',
                                "type": "POST",
                                "url": sSource,
                                "data": aoData,
                                "success": function (json)
                                {
                                        fnCallback(json);
                                        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
                                        document.getElementById("bottom").focus();
                                },
                                "error": function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                                        alert("An Error Occurred.!");
                                }
                });
```

The issue is that when I run the search and datatables renders "Processing ..." text the "Show .. Search" and first next previous and last button also gets displayed. Is there a way that I defer there display when datatabales has processed or received response from backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include `"bPaginate": false,` into the configuration object you pass to your constructor parameters.

As seen [here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/filter_only.html).
 as it is data table

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand your question completly. If you want to hide those controlls you may try this..

Datatables comes with controls for filtering and pagination. These can be shown and hidden in a couple of ways (all examples in coffeescript):
Way 1

```
$("#myTable").dataTable
"bPaginate": false, #hide pagination control
"bFilter": false #hide filter control
```

Way 2: Use the "sDom" prop

```
$("#myTable").dataTable
"aaData": data
"sDom": 'ft'
```

Here 'f' means filter and 't' means table, so only show those. Order matters: 'ft' puts
the filter on top, whereas 'tf' will put it on bottom.

For more complex and other widgets, see Ref
Ref: http://datatables.net/usage/options#sDom

I got the answer from this link : https://gist.github.com/1568446

Answer (score 0):

```css
//Hide DataTables Length
<style>.dataTables_length {
  display: none;
}

</style> //Hide Pagination
<style>.pagination {
  display: none;
}

</style> //Hide DataTables Info
<style>.dataTables_info {
  display: none;
}

</style>
```

This will work,but i am not recommending this

Answer (score 0):

Note that this answer is consistent with version DataTables 1.13.1

This is all set with the arguments object given to initialize the table

```
const myTable = $('#example').dataTable( args );
```

To avoid Next / Previous / First / Last buttons on pagination:

```
const args = {pagingType: "numbers"};
```

Find [here](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html) the 6 choices available for pagingType property

To show/hide the searching box:

```
const args = {searching: true/false};
```

I hope this helps